# What in the world is this?

Tags: riddle, poetry

> Lots of people pluck me in into what they plug in
>
> For they do not need me to do what I give them
>
> But they prefer me over the other
>
> Because I’m more collectible
>
> Everyone got to have me
>
> For they need to give the price of sixty
>
> But most youngsters have a collection of me anyway
>
> And I’m coming in a box to them on their birthday

Comment: Why the downvote? I suspect there’s someone who’s camping just to downvote people’s puzzles.

Comment: The question is being downvoted because it is a simple question. (being brutally honest) I figured out most of the question from a single glance. It is not very interesting to do. It may be hard, but not interesting.

Comment: −1 because  (1) I have never heard the word “pluck” used in the context that the accepted answer suggests you mean it to be used. Nor can I find any such usage / definition in a quick online search. But it goes deeper than that. “Pluck” and “into” don’t go together; you pluck something ***from*** something.  (2) “they prefer me over the other” seems to be your opinion. And maybe the opinion of 50% of the people who have an opinion. Or maybe 70 or 80% — but it is an *opinion*, and so not a great clue.  (3) “Everyone got to have me” is clearly hyperbole — not to mention ungrammatical. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) The “sixty” clue may be immediately meaningful to a small portion of the United States population — but not me, and definitely not my parents.  I expect that it is known to *very* few people who do not frequent the US.

Comment: Like dude, I do not even live in the US, these are not my prices, and it’s my first riddle, so like, some stupid shenanigans.

Comment: @PeregrineRook I swear, I thought the "60" was referring to US electric mains being 60 Hz, whereas in Europe it is 50 Hz. I guess I went down that path cuz I saw the words "plug in" and thought electrical outlets. But it did not compel me to downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is:

> CD video game buying!

Lots of people pluck me in into what they plug in

> You pluck it into a console or a PC, depending what you play on.

For they do not need me to do what I give them

> You do not need to buy a physical copy, because the online will work too.

But they prefer me over the other

> I, personally prefer online copy, but some prefer the disc because...

Because I’m more collectible

> You can make a collection out of CDs.

Everyone got to have me

> A lot of people want certain videogames.

For they need to give the price of sixty

> Most videogames on the market are 60 dollars.

But most youngsters have a collection of me anyway

> A lot of kids already have a lot of videogames.

And I’m coming in a box to them on their birthday

> A lot of children want videogames on their birthday.

Comment: It is a little wrong and can you be more specific on videogame? Like videogame isn’t the right word and the start kind of has wrong answers, so 55% correct.

Comment: @maounkhan may be it is x-box (preferred over Nintendo)

Comment: Nope, it has something to do with the actual videogame, he didn’t answer the second line correctly, same with the third, if he answered those correctly he would have the right answer.

Comment: @maounkhan Could you give me a hint for line 2 and 3?

Comment: Video games have two methods of getting the game, so this is referring to those methods, and this method being the preferred the one most of the time.

Comment: rot13(Ivqrb tnzr qvfp bire ohlvat gur bayvar irefvba cebonoyl - fb gung jnl lbh pna unir n culfvpny pbyyrpgvba.)

Comment: @maounkhan I fixed it, but your answer is technically incorrect because a lot of people prefer rot13(Bayvar ivqrb tnzr fubccvat.)

Comment: Did you check the internet.